# Java SimpleDateFormat throws no ParseException

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing

i want parse some Dates.. i do this with the following code:

```
ULocale tmpLocale=Locale.US

try {
        return parse(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",tmpLocale);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {

        try {
            return parse(date, "dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm",tmpLocale);
        } catch (ParseException e2) {
            try {
                return parse(date, "dd.MM.yyyy",tmpLocale);
            } catch (ParseException e3) {
                try {
                    return parse(date, "yyyy-MM-dd",tmpLocale);
                } catch (ParseException e4) {

                    try{

                        return parse(date, "yyyyMMdd",tmpLocale);

                    }catch(ParseException e5){


                        throw new DefaultDateParserException();

                    }

                }//e4 catch
            }//e3 catch
        }//e2 Catch

    } //e1 Catch
```

and the parsing is done by this method:

```
private static DateValue parse(String value, String pattern,ULocale locale) throws ParseException {

UFormat uFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale);
((SimpleDateFormat) uFormat).setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
((SimpleDateFormat) uFormat).setLenient(false);

Date date = ((SimpleDateFormat) uFormat).parse(value);

GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
gc.setTime(date);

return new DateValue(gc);
```

}

To test if the Exceptions are thrown i use this test value "2011.10.01"... no pattern in my code above should match to this, but the Exception e4 
"parse(date, "yyyyMMdd",tmpLocale);" did parse my date, why is this so ? "yyyyMMdd" should not match to this date "2011.10.01" ! how can i tell my parser that he should only parse my date it the pattern match exactly?

Hope you understand what i mean.

EDIT: It seems the problem is the UFormat from IBM that i use:
But i don`t know why its not working there. 
@Kyllopardiun
if you download this package 
  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j/4.0.1

and change your imports to this:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import com.ibm.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import com.ibm.icu.util.GregorianCalendar;
import com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone;
import com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale;
```

and Local.US to ULocale.US

then it throws no exception!

Comment: I just tested your code here and "2011.10.01" went all the way through exception e5.

Answer (score 0):

First: the parse shouldn't be **static** you are probably misunderstanding some concepts of OOP to be calling a method that shouldn't be static.

Secound: you always should try to follow this site guidelines and Create a **[Minimal Complete Verified Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

I have no idea how is your class `DateValue` and therefore I can't know for sure if the error isn't there.

Your code *actually works*:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class CalendarFun {
    private GregorianCalendar parse(String value, String pattern)
            throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat uFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US);
        ((SimpleDateFormat) uFormat).setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        ((SimpleDateFormat) uFormat).setLenient(false);

        Date date = ((SimpleDateFormat) uFormat).parse(value);

        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(
                TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        gc.setTime(date);

        return gc;

    }

    public static void main(String[] argvs) {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        String date = "2011.10.01";
        CalendarFun t = new CalendarFun();
        calendar = t.test(date);
        date = "10.01.2011";
        calendar = t.test(date);


    }

    public GregorianCalendar test(String date) {
        try {
            System.out.println("1o try");
            return parse(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {

            try {
                System.out.println("2nd try");
                return parse(date, "dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm");
            } catch (ParseException e2) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("3rd try");
                    return parse(date, "dd.MM.yyyy");
                } catch (ParseException e3) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("4th try");
                        return parse(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
                    } catch (ParseException e4) {

                        try {
                            System.out.println("5th try");
                            return parse(date, "yyyyMMdd");

                        } catch (ParseException e5) {

                            System.out.println("error");

                        }

                    }// e4 catch
                }// e3 catch
            }// e2 Catch

        }
        return new GregorianCalendar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, first thx for your help, it seems the problem is the UFormat from IBM that i use i have edited my first post. If i use the IBM package then no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

What about just defining multiple patterns? They might come from a config file containing known patterns, hard coded it reads like:

```
private List<SimpleDateFormat> patterns = new ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat>();        

    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"));

    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm"));

    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd"));
    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy"));

    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    patterns.add(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

and then, you can loop through all the patterns that you saved in List.

```
private Date getDateByPattern() {
    String s = "2015-10-05";
    for (int i = 0; i < patterns.size(); i++) {
        SimpleDateFormat pattern = (SimpleDateFormat) patterns.get(i);
        try {
            date = pattern.parse(s);
        } catch(ParseException e) {
            continue;
        }
        if(date != null) {
            System.out.println("pattern: " + pattern.toLocalizedPattern());
            System.out.println("parsed date: " + date);
            return date;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```